# Best way to old "version" of specific parameters on django model

Tags: python, django

I want to do a "version control" kind of thing.

I have a django model called "Person"

I also have a method of updating all persons "gender" and "language" according to "detection" version. this method improves from version to version.
I dont want to "detect" gender of person in latest version to not over use resources, each detection cost ...

my method need to run over all persons with gender version 1 or language version 1 and update the person lang and gen to version 2 (run the method).

so the simple is:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    gender_version = int ...
    language = models.ManyToManyField(
        "instagram_data.Language", verbose_name=_("language_code_name"), blank=True)
    language_version = int ...
```

but I have also 20 more filters (like gen and lang) so I prefer to have one attribute named version, so I could filter also in a simple way.
if I do ManyToManyField to class Version it will be slow to do filters, right ?

```
class Person(models.Model):
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    language = models.ManyToManyField(
        "instagram_data.Language", verbose_name=_("language_code_name"), blank=True)
    version_control = models.ManyToManyField(DetectionVersion ...)

class DetectionVersion(models.Model):
    gender_version = int ...
    language_version = int ..
```

is the second fast and a good solution ?